# Way to batch hide for render?

Tags: rendering, interface, shortcut

How can I disable rendering for a large amount of objects quickly using, say a keyboard short cut. I want it to be equivalent to clicking the camera icon in the outliner.

Comment: esc pauses, esc again will destroy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the mesh, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. The mesh will still be visible in the viewport, but it will now be hidden in the render.

As you can see it is visible in the viewport render still:

[image]

However if I press <kbd>F12</kbd> and render an image, it is hidden.

[image]

This works for any number of objects, just select them all, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Notice also that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> unhides the selected meshes from the final render.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if an object has been hidden from rendering without actually rendering the scene?

Comment: @PGmath The outliner, or go to *`N` menu > Display > Only Render*